# Spring 3.1 Cache namespace problem

Tags: spring, caching

i am trying to use 3.1 spring cache configuration and namespaces as per [spring doc](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.0.M1/spring-framework-reference/html/cache.html). i have also downloaded latest jar from spring site but still i am getting 
this problem regarding namespaces

```
Unable to locate Spring NamespaceHandler for element 'cache:annotation-driven' of schema namespace 'http://www.springframework.org/
```

schema/cache'

spring config file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"   xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:jee="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee" xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
xmlns:cache="http://www.springframework.org/schema/cache"
xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-2.5.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-2.5.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee-2.5.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-2.5.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/cache http://www.springframework.org/schema/cache/spring-cache.xsd">


cache:annotation-driven />

<bean id="cacheManager" class="org.springframework.cache.ehcache.EhCacheCacheManager" p:cache-manager-ref="ehcache"/>
<bean id="ehcache" class="org.springframework.cache.ehcache.EhCacheManagerFactoryBean" 
    p:config-location="classpath:ehcache.xml"/>
```

Comment: I assume the missing `<` is a mistake when pasting.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you need `spring-context-support.jar` and  `spring-context.jar` on the classpath.

`spring-context` has the `CacheNamespaceHandler` class.

(note that spring is now using a different naming scheme for their jars, but `context` and `context support` are retained in the names)

Comment: @Bozho i have added spring-context.jar but i cudn,t find spring-cache.jar in the downloaded source

Comment: @Bozho org.springframework.context.support-3.1.0.M1.jar is already aded in my project.should i add pring-context-support-2.5.6.jar

Comment: @Bozho where i can get that jar..i am not able to find that

Comment: in the download section, from the zip: spring-framework-3.1.0.M1.zip

Comment: @Bozho sorry to bother you again nd again..but adding but these jars were alredy present.. :( nd still cache anotation is not working

Comment: the annotation, or you get the above exception about the handler? If the exception is resolved, I believe we can close this question, and you can ask a new one about the new problem.

Comment: unfortunately problem is not solved here also..that why i am insisting on same thing

Comment: remove the 2.5.6 jar. Clean your classpath from all older versions. It works for me with these two jars that I listed.

Answer (score 3):

For Maven users, add the following dependency:

```
    <spring-version>3.1.0.RELEASE</spring-version>
    <ehcache-version>2.4.2</ehcache-version>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>${spring-version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
        <version>${spring-version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.sf.ehcache</groupId>
        <artifactId>ehcache-core</artifactId>
        <version>${ehcache-version}</version>
    </dependency>
```